# How to update the quantity in my array in the local storage

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, local-storage, push

I'm creating a shopping cart where in if I add to cart, the quantity should be added to the previous quantity. In my case it only sets to a quantity and is not adding.

Here is the code that I tried:

```
var addNewItem = function (name, quantity, price) {

   // retrieve it (Or create a blank array if there isn't any info saved yet),
   var items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('itemsInCart')) || [];


  // add to it,
   items.push({name: name, quantity: quantity, price: price});

   //supposed to add to quantity
   for (var item of items){
      if(item.name === name){
        quantity += item.quantity ;
        console.log('true');     
      }
   }

   // then put it back.
   localStorage.setItem('itemsInCart', JSON.stringify(items));
   console.log(items);
}
```

Comment: try printing `item.name` and `name`

Comment: If there are no items, then `for (var item of items)` will not iterate on anything. Place a `console.log()` statement as the first line in your `for` loop and see if it prints.  Better yet, use your browser's breakpoint and debug capabilities.

Comment: Oh it gives me an error. It cant  read property 'name'.. Woops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just needed a slight modification to the addition logic.

You need to check if it already exists in the `itemsInCart` array before pushing it.

```
var addNewItem = function(name, quantity, price) {

  // retrieve it (Or create a blank array if there isn't any info saved yet),
  var items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('itemsInCart')) || [];


  // add to it, only if it's empty
  var item = items.find(item => item.name === name);

  if (item) {
    item.quantity += quantity;
  } else {
    items.push({
      name,
      quantity,
      price
    })
  }

  // then put it back.
  localStorage.setItem('itemsInCart', JSON.stringify(items));
  console.log(items);
}
```